# Getting the last element from array as every

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have this problem which I can't resolve for a long time. I have some data wrote in csv file. I want to write these element to array of String to be able use them in next classes but every element in the array is equal the last one and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I need help in this.

In this class I'm reading from saved.csv file and writing this to array of String and next I'm checking this writing by writing this elements back into new csv file - check, but instead of getting different values in every line I have the same as in the last.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
Button button2;
Button button3;
DescriptorMatcher matcher;
static String name2;
static String color2;
String x2;
String y2;
float xsec;
float ysec;
Mat desc2;
static String descriptor2;
InputStream fis = null;
String line;
String path  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Objects";
File file = new File(path+"/saved.csv");
File file2 = new File(path+"/check.csv");
int numer = 0;
public static String[] dataToSave = null;
public static ObjectRep[] objectTab = new ObjectRep[25];


static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
    }
}
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this)
{
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:  // Callback method, called after OpenCV library initialization
            {
                FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB); //or BRISK
                MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
                Mat descriptors= new Mat();
               // desc2 = new Mat();
                DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB); //32Bytes per KeyPoint
                DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMINGLUT);

            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    readAndWrite();
    Log.d("Name of 5 " + objectTab[5].name, "x" + objectTab[5].x);
    Log.d("Name of 0 "+objectTab[0].name,"x "+objectTab[0].x);
    Log.d("Name of 1 "+objectTab[1].name,"x "+objectTab[1].x);
    Log.d("Name of 3 "+objectTab[3].name,"x "+objectTab[3].x);
    for(int i=0; i<objectTab.length; i++) {
        dataToSave = new String[]{objectTab[i].name, objectTab[i].color, objectTab[i].desc.toString(), String.valueOf(objectTab[i].x), String.valueOf(objectTab[i].y)};

        save(file2, dataToSave);
    }

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setFocusable(true);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddingObject.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LookObject.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

// Before 2.0
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void readAndWrite() {
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        if (fis != null) {

            // prepare the file for reading
            InputStreamReader chapterReader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(chapterReader);
            int j = 1;
            // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++, j++) {
                // do {
                line = buffreader.readLine();
                if (j == 1) {
                    name2 = line;
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    color2 = line;
                } else if (j == 3) {

                    descriptor2 = line;

                    File image = new File(descriptor2);
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
                    desc2 = new Mat(bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, desc2);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(desc2, desc2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
                    //desc2 = Imgcodecs.imread(descriptor2);
                } else if (j == 4) {
                    x2 = line;
                    xsec = Float.valueOf(x2);
                } else if (j == 5) {
                    y2 = line;
                    ysec = Float.valueOf(y2);

                    j = 0;
                    objectTab[numer] = null;
                    objectTab[numer] = new ObjectRep(name2, color2, desc2, xsec, ysec);
                    Log.d("Przedmiot" + objectTab[numer].name, " ");
                    if(i==5){
                        Log.d("Przedmiot i=5" + objectTab[5].name, " ");
                    }

                    clear();
                    if (objectTab[numer] != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Object added ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    numer++;
                }

            }


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "adding failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        // close the file.
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



public static void save(File file, String[] data)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    try
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            if (br.readLine() != null) {
                fos.write("\n".getBytes());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
            {

                fos.write(data[i].getBytes());
                if (i < data.length-1)
                {
                    fos.write("\n".getBytes());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}


public void clear(){
    name2 = null;
    color2 = null;
    x2 = null;
    y2 = null;
    xsec = 0;
    ysec = 0;
    descriptor2 = null;
    desc2 = null;

}
```

}

Class to write elements :

```
public class ObjectRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static String name;
public static String color;
private byte []descriptors;
private int cols;
private int rows;
private int elemSize;
private int MatType;
public static float x;
public static float y;
Mat desc;




public ObjectRep(String name,String color, Mat desc, float x, float y){
    this.name=name;
    this.desc = desc;
    MatToBytes(desc);
    this.color=color;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}



public Byte MatToBytes(Mat data){
    cols=data.cols();
    rows=data.rows();
    elemSize=(int)data.elemSize();
    MatType=data.type();
    descriptors=new byte[(int)(data.total()*data.elemSize())]; // elemSize is in bytes
    data.get(rows, cols, descriptors);
    return null;            //??
}


public  Mat bytesToMat(){
    if(descriptors!=null){
        Mat desc = new Mat(rows, cols, MatType);
        desc.put(0, 0, descriptors);
        return desc;
    }else return null;
}
```

}

saved.csv :

> table black /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/table_black.jpg
>   700.0
>   435.0 blabla blabla /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/blabla_blabla.jpg
>   117.0
>   348.0 somesome somesome /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/somesome_somesome.jpg
>   641.0
>   298.0 nanana nanana /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/nanana_nanana.jpg
>   129.0
>   392.0 something something /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/something_something.jpg
>   299.0
>   504.0 laptop white /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg
>   404.0
>   572.0

and after that I have my new check.csv which looks like this:

> laptop white /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg
>   404.0
>   572.0 laptop white /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg
>   404.0
>   572.0 laptop white /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg
>   404.0
>   572.0 laptop white /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg
>   404.0
>   572.0 laptop white /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg
>   404.0
>   572.0

I appreciate every help

Comment: What do you programme print ? in Log.d("Nazwa 5" + objectTab[5].name, "x" + objectTab[5].x);
    Log.d("Nazwa 0"+objectTab[0].name,"x"+objectTab[0].x);
    Log.d("Nazwa 1"+objectTab[1].name,"x"+objectTab[1].x);
    Log.d("Nazwa 3"+objectTab[3].name,"x"+objectTab[3].x);

Comment: Oh sorry, this is random checking of 5th, 0, 1st and 3d element to be sure about name and x, but in every "i" I'm getting "laptop" as name and "404.0" as x, instead of other values.

Comment: What is your log output during this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
} else if (j == 5) {

...

objectTab[numer] = new ObjectRep(name2, color2, desc2, xsec, ysec);

...
```

When you read the file you only load objectTab **when j = 5**.

Comment: I think it's ok, I because I debuged this, and when j=5 every line is read and then I can create this object. Object is created correctly but after this method when I want to write this array to new file it sees only the last object and overwrite to every.

Comment: I think your source file is different from that are you showing in the question. Because based on the logic yuo only have a value per line.

Comment: Yes, this is csv file and in every line is different value but in the same schema : 1)name 2) color 3) path to jpg file 4)x 5)y

Comment: and your final file have only one element ? and it's laptop white ?

Comment: Final file has all over again 1)laptop 2)white 3)  /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg 4) 404.0 5)572.0 6)laptop 7)white 8) /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picFolder/laptop_white.jpg and so on, but in theory it's creating new object of ObjectRep correctly but when I'm calling this later in every element is the same object and I have no idea why.

Comment: I've Found it it's because in your ObjectRep  you have this two vriable like static public static String name;
public static String color;   when you use static there is only one instance of that variable. If you remove the static your program will work

Comment: Hi! Thank you, yes! I had some others problems but now I can see everythng is ok ;)) Once again thank you, I forogot about this :)

Comment: Mark the answer so it could help others